# @Autowired during testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have a question.

@Autowired annotation is not recomended since Spring Boot 2.x. Then I have to use constructor.

[image]

but in during testing (JUnit 5) i don't have any warning

[image]

Questions:

that means using @Autowired during testing is good practicle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**field injection** is not recommended for a several of concepts, most of them connected to the usage of the class in other places, e.g the class can be instantiate with the default (no-args) constructor, thus will not be created with all or any dependencies

- because the **actual class** can be instantiate in other places like at the **testing** part of code you get this warning
- because the **testing class** *usually* isn't meant to be instantiate at any other parts of the code, you get no warning, this doesn't mean it's ok, it's still field injection and is still not recommended

you can read more about this [here](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/)

Answer (score 2):

JUnit and Spock(which is actually based on JUnit) frameworks are enforcing tests classes to have no-args constructors only. So it's not even achievable - probably that's why you weren't prompted about potential issue.

> Test classes must not be abstract and must have a single constructor.

from [junit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests)

To add a bit more to this [article](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/)

Additional pros for constructor autowiring:

- you can validate what kind of bean is being injected, either by code or by debugging tools if something suddenly stops working as expected.
- it's easier to create class instance for testing purposes, especially if it has private/protected attributes that should be mocked and you are writing tests in pure java.